# rosrun doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

I'm new to ROS and I'm following the next tutorial (Don't worry there is time stamps bellow to see the full code in the video).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqYvMEYJoTk&list=PLAjUtIp46jDcQb-MgFLpGqskm9iB5xfoP&ab_channel=EmilVidmark

the thing is that my code is identical to the python executable (11:10) and I wrote the same thing in the CMakeLists.txt under line 111 (12:34) additionally I granted an execute permission to the python file with the command.

chmod +x publisher_node

but when I run the rosrun command it does nothing, it's not freezing but it is not under the rostopic list.

rosrun tutorials publisher_node.py

i'm running with another terminal running the roscore and I've the Ubuntu 18.04 distro.
Thanks in advance for your help!.

Edit:

The question was closed because I didn't add enough detail, I didn't know if I should add more detail because there is a warning that I should wrap things up, so here is my full procedure

I ran the following commands from the base folder of Ubuntu Terminal:

```
usr@PC:~$ mkdir python_catkin
usr@PC:~$ cd python_catkin
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ mkdir src
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/usr/python_catkin
Source space: /home/usr/python_catkin/src
Build space: /home/usr/python_catkin/build
Devel space: /home/usr/python_catkin/devel
Install space: /home/usr/python_catkin/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/usr/python_catkin/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/usr/python_catkin/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/usr/python_catkin/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/usr/python_catkin/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/usr/python_catkin/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/usr/python_catkin/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'tutorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(tutorials)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/usr/python_catkin/build
####
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ cd src
usr@PC:~/python_catkin/src$ catkin_create_pkg tutorials rospy std_msgs
Created file tutorials/package.xml
Created file tutorials/CMakeLists.txt
Created folder tutorials/src
Succesfully created files in home/usr/python_catkin/src/tutorials. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
```

Later I opened Visual Studio Code under the tutorials folder and created the folder scripts and I created a file under the scripts folder named publisher_node.py, then I added this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talk_to_me():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('talking_topic', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('publisher_node', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1)
    rospy.loginfo("Publisher Node Started, now publishing messages")
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg = "Hello Emil - %s" % rospy.get(time)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talk_to_me()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

later under the CMakeLists.txt file I added the following line:

```
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/publisher_node.py
  DESTINATION %{CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

later I went to the folder of the ROS proyect on a terminal and runned the following command:

Terminal1:

```
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ roscore
... logging to /home/usr/.ros/log/710a4f1c-3c3e-11ed-8cef-409f3849b403/roslaunch-PC-9343.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://IP/
ros_comm version 1.14.13


SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.13

NODES

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [9355]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://IP/
```

Terminal2:

```
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ rosrun tutorials publisher_node.py
█
```

The Terminal2 is running but it doesn't print anything, it doesn't print the line 9 nor the line 11 from the publisher_node.py, it just stays the same when I give it excecution permissions but if I don't it shows the error message:

Terminal2:

```
usr@PC:~/python_catkin$ rosrun tutorials publisher_node.py
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named publisher_node.py below /home/usr/python_catkin/src/tutorials
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/usr/python_catkin/src/tutorials/scripts/publisher_node.py
```

I hope is well explained, if you have any question please answer this post and I will respond ASAP.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the Robotics SE site Alexander. Thanks for linking to the tutorial that you're following. However you need to be able to provide a reproducible description of what you're doing for us to help you. If you were everything that's in the tutorial the same then you should get the same result. As such if we were to try to help you we'd be looking for what you did differently. But you have not documented what you're doing so it's impossible to help you find what you're doing differently. Please edit this question to provide enough information to concretely reproduce your problem.

Comment: We prefer *[practical, answerable questions ](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: You need to find out what it's doing. Such as running it in pdb, or adding printouts at each line. Making sure that you're running the code that you think you are. Finding where it stops will tell you a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your roscore log, I see that your ROS_MASTER_URI is malformed. You have not included how your set up your environment, but I think that your have accidentally copied something verbatim which should have been substituted for your IP and it's missing the port number.

Make sure to check your [environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

And see [this related question](https://answers.ros.org/question/272065/specification-of-ros_master_uri-and-ros_hostname/)